# Comfortable number of server files in a folder

Tags: php, directory

I'm building a website which holds its images in relevant folder, but I was wondering how to structure the folder paths ( `month/year/` or just `year/` )

I will be getting the images via php, so the scripting will look like:

`files/cover_photo/$year/$month/$id.jpg`

I don't really know how many images I'm going to be posting but was wondering how many images is a comfortable number in each folder if they are going to be selected using the `PHP` script above.

I don't want to risk slowing my site down by having too many images per directory, but at the same time I don't want to have too many directories with few files inside.

Can anyone give me any advice?

Comment: If you are asking about the filesystem path, then the hard "limit" is imposed by the OS, not PHP.

Answer (score 2):

There is not really a "right answer" to this.

Sorting by year/month is not a bad option, because it's easy to implement and it scales well.

There's no need to worry about empty directories though - just create the directories when you need them (i.e. the first time there's an upload in that year or month).

This is the way [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org) does it.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I'll go with the `year/month` option as it makes more sense to me that way anyway!

Comment: No problem. :) I should note that you can accept an answer if it has helped you by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer (you don't _have_ to do this, but it does help future users plus gives some rep to the person who has answered - I just mention it because I notice you haven't accepted an answer yet so might not know how it works). There's some more info in the help centre [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). Good luck with the project!